# actix_web middleware logger output to file

Tags: logging, rust, actix-web

I currently have the logger outputting to the terminal, using the code below. However, web pages aren't loading until a key has been pressed in the terminal. Is there a way to output the logs to a file. I can't seem to find anything in the official documentation. [actix_web middleware documentation](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/middleware/struct.Logger.html)

```
use actix_web::{middleware::Logger, get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use env_logger::Env;

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[post("/echo")]
async fn echo(req_body: String) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(req_body)
}

async fn manual_hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hey there!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    env_logger::init_from_env(Env::default().default_filter_or("info"));
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .service(hello)
            .service(echo)
            .route("/hey", web::get().to(manual_hello))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: env_logger doesn't support logging to files. You'll probably have to use another library to get the logs to write to a file. Try looking into the log4rs create or the slog crate. As an alternative you can always implement or create your own way to log to a file with Actix. If you want I can post an answer of how I have done it in the past.

Comment: Please @AustinHamner can you post your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a mod file called logger.rs and brought it into scope from lib.rs. I used the crates "colored" and "chrono"

- logger.rs

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::Path;
use colored::{Colorize, control};
use chrono::Local;

// Path to log file
const LOG_PATH: &str = "ServerLogs.log";

/// List of different types of log headers.
pub enum Header {
    SUCCESS,
    INFO,
    WARNING,
    ERROR
}

/// Logs a message to the console.
pub fn log(header: Header, message: &str) {
    // Type of message to log
    let header = match header {
        Header::SUCCESS => "SUCCESS".bold().bright_green(),
        Header::INFO => "INFO".bold().bright_blue(),
        Header::WARNING => "WARNING".bold().bright_yellow(),
        Header::ERROR => "ERROR".bold().bright_red()
    };

    // Print the log to the console
    control::set_virtual_terminal(true).unwrap();
    println!("[{}] {} {}", Local::now().format("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S").to_string().bold(), header, message);

    // Write the log to a file
    if Path::new(LOG_PATH).exists() {
        let mut log_file = OpenOptions::new().append(true).open(LOG_PATH).unwrap();
        writeln!(log_file, "[{}] {} {}", Local::now().format("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S").to_string(), header.clear(), message).unwrap();
    } else {
        let mut log_file = OpenOptions::new().create_new(true).append(true).open(LOG_PATH).unwrap();
        writeln!(log_file, "[{}] {} {}", Local::now().format("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S").to_string(), header.clear(), message).unwrap();
    }
}
```

- lib.rs

```
pub mod logger;
```

and now you can call the log function from anywhere in your code like so:

```
#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
    logger::log(Header::SUCCESS, "Hello world!");
}

#[post("/echo")]
async fn echo(req_body: String) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(req_body)
    logger::log(Header::INFO, format!("echo: {}", req_body).as_str());
}

async fn manual_hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hey there!")
    logger::log(Header::WARNING, "Hey there!");
}
```

Here is what it will look like in the log file:

```
[09-27-2022 13:32:56] SUCCESS Hello world!
[09-27-2022 13:41:25] INFO echo: test
[09-27-2022 13:59:48] WARNING Hey there!
```

Please feel free to edit and modify the code however you'd like to make it work best in your project. I hope this helps.